# How do I execute an exe command in JAVA?

Tags: java, command, exe

I have an exe file which takes a file name as input.
When I execute it as a command like:

`xyz.exe c:\input.txt c:\ouput.txt`

It all works as expected.

But how to execute this is java?

This is the one i used and am not getting the ouput in the files:

```
String[] str = {"c:/input.txt","c:/output.txt"};
Process p = rt.exec("c:/xyz.exe",str);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the method:

```
public Process exec(String command,
                    String[] envp)
```

where `envp` is a ([quote](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)) *"array of strings, each element of which has environment variable settings in the format name=value, or null if the subprocess should inherit the environment of the current process."*

Try this instead:

```
String[] command = {"c:/xyz.exe", "c:/input.txt", "c:/output.txt"}; 
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
// ...
```

Also read this article that explains the pitfalls of `Runtime.exec(...)`: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Runtime.exec or  Processbuilder API

Comment: String[] str={"c:/input.txt","c:/output.txt"};Process p = rt.exec("c:/xyz.exe",str); This is the one i used and am not getting the ouput in the files.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should answer your question http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/133710

Comment: Found the work around Thanks..String[] str={"c:/xyz.exe", "c:/input.txt","c:/output.txt"};Process p = rt.exec(str);